# mod_rewrite on subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cdn, cname

**It took 12 hours and dozen of posts on stackoverflow turned purple but still don't know what did I do wrong**

I'm tried to **setup cookie-free domain using mod_rewrite** on .htaccess rewriting subdomain (a1,a2,a3,a4,a5) to root.

here is what I got so far..

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a1.my-domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.my-domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

then, I uploaded to the root directory and opened a php file from the browser with this code

```
<img src="http://a1.my-domain.com/images/imgname.jpg">
```

also tried go directly to the URL

```
http://a1.my-domain.com/images/imgname.jpg
http://a1.my-domain.com/
```

but both are not working, the image didn't show up, *while other codes in .htaccess works just fine*. Could you please suggest a solution on this?

////////////// **EDIT MORE INFO** //////////////

According to - http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/03/12/use-cookie-free-domain-and-cdn-for-static-content/ - I want to setup a Cookie Free Domain without moving resources to the subdomain and to create a pararel load which, from what I understand, increase connection when the website load and in the same time make it cookie free.

I want to load the html below

```
<img src="http://www.my-domain.com/images/imageA.jpg">
<img src="http://www.my-domain.com/images/imageB.jpg">
<img src="http://www.my-domain.com/images/imageC.jpg">
```

using these below (pointing 'a*.my-domain.com' to 'www.my-domain.com')

```
<img src="http://a1.my-domain.com/images/imageA.jpg">
<img src="http://a2.my-domain.com/images/imageB.jpg">
<img src="http://a3.my-domain.com/images/imageC.jpg">
```

By reading  about Cookie-Free, I just need to create a subdomain and point it to the root www but, as my host provides DirectAdmin control panel, I can't point subdomain anywhere but the subfolder with its name and I don't have access to Apache for modifying a Virtual Host configuration. So, I tried to use .htaccess to do it. Can you suggest how to do it? and I'm quite new to this so, please correct me if I misunderstood. Thank you :)

Comment: Do you have `RewriteEngine on` ?

Comment: @ScottHepler yes I have Options +FollowSymLinks and RewriteEngine on at the beginning of the .htaccess

Comment: Is your DNS setup properly (IOW do all of these actually point to the machine where you're doing the rewrites)?

Comment: @ScottHepler I have to setup DNS again? I thought .htaccess will redirect this without having to setup DNS. Setting up takes a while, I'll come back to tell you the progress again, Thank you very much

Comment: well, if the request for a1. is to hit your rewrite, it has to be able to find its way there -- your logs are your friends on this

Comment: Simple solution for DNS here might be to use a wildcard, instead of specifying `a1`, `a2`, `a3` etc, you would use `*` - ie, anything.

Comment: @Patrick Thank you, I'm thinking of using http://res.a1.my-domain.com/ so I would be able to categorize resources for various modules in the website. Very useful tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off what you've been saying in the comments, it sounds like you are trying to increase load times by spreading content across multiple hostnames, so more stuff is loaded in parallel.

An A record is a host - you would use this if you wanted a physical sub directory directory.

A CNAME is an alias, and points to another address. It's simply a 'pretty URL' masking something else, if you will.

Sounds like you need a CNAME, not an A record.

Unlike my comment earlier, as far as I am aware, you need to specify all your CNAMEs. Each CNAME `a1` `a2` etc would point to your root domain.

You then need to add `a1.domain.com` as aliases to your domain in your web control panel.

Specify each hostname and redirect it with .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.* [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.tld/subdomain/ [L]
```

I'm not sure, but propagation *might* be an issue here, I forget if CNAMES are instantly accessible or not...

Comment: According to - http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2010/03/12/use-cookie-free-domain-and-cdn-for-static-content/ - I want to setup a Cookie Free Domain without moving resources to the subdomain and to create a pararel load which, from what I understand, increase connection when the website load and in the same time make it cookie free.

Comment: Character limit so, I put some more info on the topic. Thank you :)

Comment: Yes I can. here is what I did http://img211.imageshack.us/img211/8939/20120906175732.jpg

Comment: If you go to `a1.domain.com/images/image.jpg`, or whatever an image address is, does it display the image? Would have thought the CNAME should be pointed to the `/images/` folder, not just the root domain.

Comment: I tried to go a1.domain.com/images/image.jpg, it doesn't display the image. I did try to go a1.domain.com, it doesn't redirect me to the root as well. So, I can't set the subdomain to root? I don't want to move my images to different subdomains.

Comment: CNAME will just get the content from the specified location, it won't visually relocate you. http://www.totally-awesome-tees.com/ All the images on that site are derived from a CDN, have a look at the image addresses, all are cdn1-4.totally-awesome-tees.com.  Have you added `a1.domain.com` `a2.domain.com` `a3.domain.com` etc as aliases for your domain name in your web control panel?

Comment: It seems you can't CNAME to a directory, and you do indeed need to use mod_rewrite. I have updated my answer to match. It seems like you are just missing the alias of these hostnames to your domain in your web control panel...

Comment: I can't simply add alias but, I found Add New Domain Pointer which point to www.a1.my-domain.com and in the same time add alias for me. Right now, YSlow allow me to Add it as CDN so, this should work, right?

Comment: It worked! I removed www and I got a1.my-domain.com as I wanted. The site will later move to a dedicated server so I tried to do use a subdomain CDN optimization even without Apache access. However, thank you so much for your help, Patrick :D

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a1.my-domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.my-domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

why not give a try to this

```
RewriteRule ^a1.my-domain.com$ http://www.my-domain.com/a1 [L]
```

Comment: Still got "Forbidden - You don't have permission to access / on this server."

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^www\.my-domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)         http://www.my-domain.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

from [the Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/remapping.html)?

Comment: My host do not allow admin access to the Apache. I put .htaccess on the root of the website where index.php is.

Comment: @Rik: this just goes in your .htaccess instead of what you have above -- but you'll still need to be sure the DNS bits are sorted before any of this has a chance of working.

Comment: I think the DNS bits has sort but still no luck. I add a1 to DNS A point to the the same IP as www. Did I do it right? This website - http://www.riyaz.net/blogging/setup-own-cdn/890/ said I need to add CNAME, I don't know if it's the same for my case. I'm still trying. It's very confusing when I don't have access to the Apache. However, Thank you very much for helping so far, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe you could tell us the real domains and one or two real resources there and then we could help you better.  DNS records only point to "machines" -- services and directories are handled by rules on those machines.

Comment: Right now, I'm able to use subdomain CDN without modifying .htaccess by using alias. Seems like the problem was about domain alias from the first place. Thank you again, :D

Answer (score 0):

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^forums$|^forums/$ index.php [R,L]
RewriteRule ^forums/([-_a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30})$ forums/$1/ [R,L]
RewriteRule ^forums/([-_a-zA-Z0-9]{3,30})/(.*)$ phpBB3/$2?access_name=$1 [QSA,L]
```

this code how to change in subdomain not example.com/forums/test
and become so test.example.com